# SVG transformation not working in Web Version of a React-Native-SVG app, but working in mobile?

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

IM a having a very WEIRD bug here.

Im doing an application where the user can zoom in and out and draw some stuff inside a SVG screen using react-native-svg.

In my mobile application running on a simulator the transformation works perfectlly.

In the same app, running as a webapp (expo start --web) no transformation its never applied. Even If I hard code it on the matrix.

This is part of my code that matters:

```
export default class DrawView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      currentMax: 0,
      currentPoints: [],
      reaction: new Reaction(),
      zoom: 1,
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      transformerMatrix: { a: 1, e: 1, c: 0, f: 0 },
      startDrawing: false,
      seconds: 0,
      email: '',
      userSentData: false,
      showPopUp: false
    };
```

This is a simple transformer Matrix. On my render method I have:

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View
      //onLayout={this._onLayoutContainer}
      style={[
        styles.drawContainer,
        this.props.containerStyle,

        { width: this.props.width, height: this.props.height }
      ]}
    >
      <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
        <Svg
          style={styles.drawSurface}
          width={this.props.width}
          height={this.props.height}
        >
          <G
            transform={{
              translateX: this.state.transformerMatrix.c,
              translateY: this.state.transformerMatrix.f,
              scale: this.state.transformerMatrix.a
            }}
          >
            {/* <Grid /> */}
            <Image
              width={'100%'}
              height={'100%'}
              preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
              opacity="1"
              href={require('../assets/images/FinalEarthGifPaletaWeb-8192x8192.gif')}
              clipPath="url(#clip)"
            />
```

If I change my transformerMatrix.a to 1.3 for instance. The image its zoomed by 30%. On Simulator it makes the transformation. But in the webApp nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

As you can see. Nothing its zoomed in on the webapp application, instead of the iOS one.

Does anyone know something related with react-native-svg not being transformed when in webApp?

Comment: following. also seeing this for ClipPath. Following works in iOS but not Web. `<Svg><Defs><ClipPath id="clip"><Rect x={-r} y={-r} width={r} height={size} /></ClipPath></Defs> <Circle
        clipPath="url(#clip)"
      /></Svg>`

Answer (score 0):

The answer for that, after trying A LOT of stuff is that, theres a bug on the library on the transform property here:

```
<G
  transform={{
    translateX: this.state.transformerMatrix.c,
    translateY: this.state.transformerMatrix.f,
    scale: this.state.transformerMatrix.a
  }}
>
```

This transform property, on iOS works well, but in web NEED to be a string:

If we change the method for a String interpolation and pass to the property, it works:

```
<G
  transform=`
    translateX: ${this.state.transformerMatrix.c},
    translateY: ${this.state.transformerMatrix.f},
    scale: ${this.state.transformerMatrix.a}
  `
>
```

Its a very tricky solution. I sent a PR to fix it on the native-svg library.

Comment: can you specify which file exactly that we can modify to fix this ? thanks

Comment: The G object. On the transform property you need to send a interpolated string. If you try to send like: transform={{
    translateX: this.state.transformerMatrix.c,
    translateY: this.state.transformerMatrix.f,
    scale: this.state.transformerMatrix.a
  }}

it will not work